# Can we use react js modules in react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

There is module called react elastic carousel for react js. I want to use it in react native for android. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, React uses HTML tags to render while React Native uses an abstraction over platform native views. They're not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

NO,

Syntax of React & React Native is similar but they both work differently,

React Native components compile into native App component while reactJS is just HTML.

You can read the [Difference Between React & React Native](https://www.cognitiveclouds.com/insights/what-is-the-difference-between-react-js-and-react-native) for better understanding